# Windows Server 2012 AD CS with Subordinate CA

Tags: active-directory, certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to setup LDAP over SSL to our brand new Windows AD Server, so I configure that role, tell him

- Enterprise CA or Standalone CA doesn't matter
- CA Type: Subordinate CA, because I already have an officially signed certificate for my domain.
- Private Key: Use existing private key
- Select a certificate and use its associated private key

And then I can chose my issued certificate for *.mydomain.com from a pfx file. But when I click next, I get an error like only Windows error can look like:

- Window headline: Error
- Inside: red circle with white cross
- OK button

So what the hell is the error, whats the problem, what I am doing wrong? As even Windows can't tell me, I'll ask here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate must contain the FQDN of the Active Directory Server, so wildcard certificates are not allowed: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321051